# Using a SELECT query as column name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, information-schema

I would like to get the values of the auto_increment column in my table (example). The catch is however, that I don't have the name of the auto_increment field. I'm currently using the following query to determine the name of the field:

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'example' AND extra = 'auto_increment' LIMIT 1;
```

I would now like to pass the result of this query, as a 'string' to my actual query, and get the value. If I would like to do this in one go, how would I do that, because the below query, which should give me all auto_increment values used, only yields the above result -namely the auto_increment column name.

```
SELECT (
   SELECT column_name
   FROM information_schema.columns
   WHERE table_name =  'example'
   AND extra =  'auto_increment'
   LIMIT 1
) AS pri
FROM example
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated :)
Many Regards,

Andreas

Comment: You can't in standard SQL. You'd have to build a new query using the results of the "get name of id column" query. Basically you need the sql equivalent of `eval()`.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  The value in the auto-increment column is not particularly interesting, just a bunch of integers.  And, are you familiar with the `prepare` statement.  You need to use dynamic SQL to do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you would do this using `prepare` and `execute`:

```
SELECT @s := concat('select `', column_name, '` from example e')
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name =  'example' AND extra =  'auto_increment'
LIMIT 1

prepare stmt from @s;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```